# openmp parallelized code in c++ is slower than the serial one

Tags: openmp

I would like to parallelise the following code

```
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
    temp = 0.
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
        temp += A[i][j]*v[j];
    u[i] = temp;
}
```

where different u[i] can be computed independently. So I tried to do

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (j,temp)
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
    temp = 0.
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
        temp += A[i][j]*v[j];
    u[i] = temp;
}
```

and I find that the second case is more slow than the first one. Any idea why it is so? here M ~ 100 and N ~ 2.

Comment: There is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17429524/5809597) for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit to parallelizing this because the data are so small: the overhead of setting up and coordinating a parallel computation outweighs any benefit of parallel execution.

Further, the calculation is easily optimized.

Your compiler will most certainly unroll the inner loop (where N=2), so that it becomes:

```
u[i] = A[i][0]*v[0] + A[i][1] * v[1]
```

Even if we assume A is a 64bit type (like double), then the outer loop over i can be unrolled 4 times, such that each access to A uses a single 64 byte cache line (for the 8 entries A[i][0] through A[i+3][1]).

The result is a single loop with only 25 iterations (for M=100):

```
for (i=0; i<M; i+= 4)
{
    u[i] = A[i][0]*v[0] + A[i][1] * v[1];
    u[i+1] = A[i+1][0]*v[0] + A[i+1][1] * v[1];
    u[i+2] = A[i+2][0]*v[0] + A[i+2][1] * v[1];
    u[i+3] = A[i+3][0]*v[0] + A[i+3][1] * v[1];
}
```

With prefetching, all accesses are basically already in cache.

You would need much bigger data to see any benefit from parallelizing this :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. Can you tell me from which size of data I would be able to see any benefit?